# Finding all attributes of HDF5 file in R - Not showing same as Python

Tags: python, r, attributes, hdf5

**Python**

When opening a `.h5` file in Python using the tables package and the code:

```
import tables as ta
h5 = ta.open_file("file.h5")
```

the `h5` file object has a large number of nodes visible within the Variables window. The information that I am looking for is within the `root` node (*type `{RootGroup}`*). Specifically there are three sub nodes:

1)  `_v_attrs` which is of type `{AttributeSet}`

2) `annotation` which is of type `{Group}`

3) `data` which is of type `{Group}`

These are all available when I access through **Python**. i.e. `tz = h5.root._v_attrs.record_timezone`

**R**

I am trying to read in these same nodes in **R** but I am not seeing all the various nodes. When I list the contents of the HDF5 file using the `hdf5` package

```
library(rhdf5)
h5ls("file.h5")
```

I am only presented with the Groups, i.e. can only see the `annotation` and `data` nodes.

```
                  group       name       otype   dclass     dim
0                      / annotation   H5I_GROUP                 
1            /annotation      epoch   H5I_GROUP                 
2      /annotation/epoch      dad12 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND      21
3      /annotation/epoch      dad18 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND      21
4      /annotation/epoch      dad24 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND      22
5      /annotation/epoch       dad4 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND      21
6      /annotation/epoch       hour H5I_DATASET COMPOUND     528
7            /annotation  hrv_rmssd   H5I_GROUP                 
8  /annotation/hrv_rmssd      dad12 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
9  /annotation/hrv_rmssd      dad18 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
10 /annotation/hrv_rmssd      dad24 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
11 /annotation/hrv_rmssd       dad4 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
12 /annotation/hrv_rmssd       hour H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
13           /annotation        raw   H5I_GROUP                 
14       /annotation/raw      dad12 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
15       /annotation/raw      dad18 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
16       /annotation/raw      dad24 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
17       /annotation/raw       dad4 H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
18       /annotation/raw       hour H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
19                     /       data   H5I_GROUP                 
20                 /data      epoch H5I_DATASET COMPOUND 1051172
21                 /data        raw H5I_DATASET COMPOUND       0
```

These are accessible using the code `data <- h5read("file.h5", "/data/epoch")` as an example.

**Question**

How do I read in the other `AttributeSet` type of nodes in R?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it not only alleviates you from HDF5 low-level details but also promotes code portability across disparate programming languages when handling HDF5 files (i.e. HDFql guarantees that the final result is always the same independently of the language used without much changes to the code).

In Python using HDFql, you can retrieve the attributes of an object (i.e. a group or a dataset) by doing the following as an example:

```
import HDFql

HDFql.execute("SHOW ATTRIBUTE my_file.h5 my_object/")

while HDFql.cursor_next() == HDFql.SUCCESS:

   print("Attribute found: %s" % HDFql.cursor_get_char())
```

In R using HDFql, this is done almost identically as in Python (see the similarity):

```
source("HDFql.R")

hdfql_execute("SHOW ATTRIBUTE my_file.h5 my_object/")

while(hdfql_cursor_next() == HDFQL_SUCCESS)
{
   print(paste("Attribute found:", hdfql_cursor_get_char()))
}
```

If you need to retrieve all the attributes across all objects stored in a HDF5 file (in a recursive way) do the following in Python (in R it will be very similar to this so I will skip posting it):

```
import HDFql

HDFql.execute("SHOW ATTRIBUTE my_file.h5 / LIKE **")

while HDFql.cursor_next():

   print("Attribute found: %s" % HDFql.cursor_get_char())
```

Additional examples on how to use HDFql both in Python and in R can be found [here](http://www.hdfql.com/examples).